# How to add a search/preview on my input tag field?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an input field which can save any tags for me in database. This working only with what I write in that field. But I want to make a preview of existing tags on that input, like tags section from stackoverflow. So, if I write `t` I want to have a preview of existing tags with first letter `t`, how can I make that?  For the moment I created a select-option function with values from `tag`, but if I don't need any tag from that list, I can't write other values instead of preview.

**Here is my view:**

```html
<div class="g-mb-30">
    <label class="g-mb-10">Tag</label>

    <div class="u-tagsinput--v2--blue g-brd-around g-brd-gray-light-v7 g-brd-gray-light-v3--focus g-rounded-4 g-px-6 g-py-5">
        <input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" name="tag" placeholder="Insert Tag" >
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is my controller with variable which gaves me tags:**

```php
public function create()
{
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = "News";
    $data['page_header'] = "News";
    $data['title'] = "News";
    $data['menu'] = "News";

    $news = News::select('tag')->distinct()->get();

    return view('news.add_news',$data)
        ->with(compact('news'));
}
```

**Here is my select option without input on**

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="g-mb-10">Tags</label>
    <select id="choices-multiple-remove-button" placeholder="Select" multiple title="Category Talent" name="talent_id[]">
        @foreach($news as $tag)
            <option value="{{ $talents->id }}">{{ $tag->tag }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: How do you make the preview on typing? I mean the JS code?

Comment: This is my problem. I don't have a preview on typing. I need to add a preview on that input field with values from `news->tag`.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/tag-editor/demo.html)?

Answer (score 0):

So,  you're looking for an autocomplete plugin. You have two options:

1. Create a plugin yourself from scratch
2. Use any already made plugin

I'll recommend you to use already made tag input plugins which support autocomplete. You can try working with TextExt(https://textextjs.com/) which is based on JQuery.

There are many other options available as well.

Comment: This isn't really what I need.I want to have a preview like here : https://imgur.com/a/K1rP1BE

Comment: Check this https://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-custom-render.html. You'll not get the exact result, but will get somewhat related result with the functionality you need. You can also try customizing it.